# Can I Update Daily My XML Sitemap

Tags: xml-sitemap

I have one website & WE will Incress Daily 10 to 20 Landing page on my website. and we update daily my xml sitemap with included new landing page.

so i ask any problem for these activity or not

Comment: If you are hoping to get these new pages indexed in search engines because you add them to the site map, it won't work.  Site maps can get Google to crawl pages but Google usually chooses not to index pages that it finds only in the site map.

Answer (score 1):

That's what most CMS(like wordpress) does automatically. Adding new URL(landing page) in sitemap is just right thing. Just submit that [sitemap to Google search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en), and if your sitemap has some error, then search console will let you know.

You can do the same for other search engine as well like [bing](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4).

Answer (score 1):

A sitemap is designed to be updated every time any new pages are added (and if you are including "modified time" or `lastmod` in your sitemap, it should also be updated whenever anything is modified).

You will not run into any issues updating your sitemap daily or even hourly if that's how often you add fresh content. Keeping your sitemap constantly up-to-date with your site can *only help* your site.